# MySQL query using different tables and filters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table called 'vacancies' which has a 'vacancy_id' PK. It looks like this:

```
    create table vacancies
(
   vacancy_id           int not null auto_increment,
   org_id               int not null,
   name                 varchar(255) not null comment 'title',
   vacancy_visibility_start_date   datetime comment 'vacancy visibility date, when it needs to be active on the website',
   vacancy_visibility_end_date     datetime,
   primary key (vacancy_id)
);
```

Following this I have a couple of other tables which are linked to this one.

```
create table vacancy_calendar
(
   vacancy_calendar_id  int not null auto_increment,
   vacancy_id           int,
   date_from            datetime not null,
   date_to              datetime not null,
   primary key (vacancy_calendar_id)
);

create table vacancy_interests
(
   vacancy_id           int,
   interest_id          int
);
create table vacancy_skills
(
   vacancy_id           int,
   skill_id             int
);
```

All of these tables can contain multiple rows for the same vacancy_id.

My page has different filters which I want to process via AJAX. 
I want to have one line per vacancy containing all data I need + it has to match my filtering criteria. However I am not sure how my query has to look like in order to retrieve the result I am looking for. 
It is possible to filter on 'interest_id' , 'skill_id', 'date_from' and 'date_to'.

I started with the following query but I am stuck very fast:

```
SELECT v.*, vi.interest_id
FROM `vacancies` as v
INNER JOIN `vacancy_interests` as vi on v.vacancy_id = vi.vacancy_id
GROUP BY v.vacancy_id
```

This query will only return me 1 interest_id for a vacancy, even if the vacancy has 3 interest_id rows in the vacancy_interest table. If I remove the GROUP BY statement I will get 3 rows for the same vacancy which is not what I want either.

Ideally I would want the interest_id's to be each in a separate column or in the same field separated by comma's. Or if there are any other possibilities/suggestions feel free to share!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group_concat for get interest_id separated by comma

```
SELECT v.*,  group_concat(vi.interest_id)
FROM `vacancies` as v
INNER JOIN `vacancy_interests` as vi on v.vacancy_id = vi.vacancy_id
GROUP BY v.vacancy_id
```

Referring to you comment about add where eg:

You can add where condition

```
SELECT v.*,  group_concat(vi.interest_id)
FROM `vacancies` as v
INNER JOIN `vacancy_interests` as vi on v.vacancy_id = vi.vacancy_id
INNER JOIN `vacancy_skills` as vs ON vs.vacancy_id  = v.vacancy_id 
WHERE vs.skill_id IN (4) AND vi.interest_id IN (1,3)
GROUP BY v.vacancy_id
```

In this case the gorup_concat is applied on the resulting rows .. because group by perform the related  action on the selected  resulting rows .

Comment: As a follow-up question: if I want to add some filtering in the WHERE statement as follows WHERE vs.skill_id IN (4) AND vi.interest_id IN (1,3). How do I go around this? Doing this would make the group_concat field always only return the integer that was passed in the where clause.

Comment: This does not work as I mentioned in my comment. Consider I have one row where the skill_id column contains the values "1,4,8" (because of the group_concat). If use my query with the vs.skill_id IN (4) where clause, the vs.skill_id column will only return me 4, whereas I also want to keep the 1 and 8 values in there as well

Comment: I don't understand if you want filter the rows vakue or the result value.. is not the same  .. if you want filter the db  row  you must usie the where clause .. if you want  filter the group_concat result if could use an havving clause  ...but your last  two comment  are a new question and is not faire reopen a question after is properly answered ..

Comment: I created another question with a followup question to this, could you take a look at this? Perhaps you can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557613/codeigniter-query-builder-having-clause-with-in-statement