# Codeigniter Query Builder having clause with IN statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

I am using CodeIgniter query builder. I want to add the having clause in there.
My code looks as follows:
(i omitted the other parts of the query):

```
$this->db->having($filterarray);
```

And i build the filterarray beforehand like this:

```
$filterarray = array();
        if (!empty($filters['interests'])) {
            $interestids = $this->interests_model->getAllIdsByDescription($filters['interests']);
            $filterarray['interests IN'] = $interestids;
        }
```

My function getAllIdsByDescription looks like this:

```
function getAllIdsByDescription($names){
    $res = "(";

    $query = $this->db->where_in('description', $names)
        ->select('interest_id')
        ->get($this->tableName);
    foreach ($query->result() as $interestid) {
        $res .= $interestid->interest_id;
        $res .= ", ";
    }
    $res = substr($res, 0, -2);
    $res .= ")";
    return $res;
}
```

It translates my query to the following, hence why I have an error:

```
HAVING interests IN '(7)'
```

How do i remove the quotes around the (7) ?

Comment: `HAVING interests IN '(7)'` -- That's not an error. The query is for a **list** of IDs, which is what you specified in the code. What "error" (or unexpected behaviour) are you actually seeing?

Comment: The problem was the quotes around the '(7)'. It got solved by using the answer from PaulD with the FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the escaping.

> If you are using a database that CodeIgniter escapes queries for, you
>   can prevent escaping content by passing an optional third argument,
>   and setting it to FALSE.

```
$this->db->having('user_id',  45);  // Produces: HAVING `user_id` = 45
$this->db->having('user_id',  45, FALSE);  // Produces: HAVING user_id = 45
```

Not sure how to implement this when just passing a single array as one argument, but you need the additional FALSE parameter.

From http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html